# How to explain strange behaviour of Groovy's reverse ranges?

Tags: groovy

```
    println GroovySystem.version
    final r = (1..10).reverse()
    final r1 = (10..1)
    assert r == r1
    assert r.takeWhile { it > 5 } == r1.takeWhile { it > 5 }
```

second assertion fails

```
2.2.2
Exception in thread "main" Assertion failed: 

assert r.takeWhile { it > 5 } == r1.takeWhile { it > 5 }
       | |                    |  |  |
       | [10, 9, 8, 7, 6]     |  |  [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
       |                      |  [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
       |                      false
       [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: With *2.4.0* it all works fine.

Comment: With 2.1.7 assert fails

Answer (score 1):

When you use `(10..1)` you've a `groovy.lang.IntRange`, instead when you apply `reverse()` on it you get a `java.util.ArrayList` result. Seems that both types behaves differently when you apply `takeWhile()` on its; at least with `2.1.7`  and `2.3.7`versions which I tested (or with `2.2.2` as OP comments), instead there is no problem with `2.4.3` or with `2.4.0` as @Opal comments. So it seems a fixed error on groovy.

If you also convert `r1` to `java.util.ArrayList` calling `toList()`, all works correctly in the groovy version you're using:

```
println GroovySystem.version
final r = (1..10).reverse()
final r1 = (10..1).toList()
assert r == r1
assert r.takeWhile { it > 5 } == r1.takeWhile { it > 5 }
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Cast it to list: `final r1 = (10..1) as List`